# Iterate through an array of hashes and combine similar elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Hi I have this array for example

```
array = [
  {ingredients: [:t1, :t2], exp: 100, result: :t5}, 
  {ingredients: [:t3, :t4], exp: 200, result: :t10},
  {ingredients: [:t1, :t2], exp:  50, result: :t6}
]
```

I want an array to look like this:

```
array = [
  {ingredients: [:t1, :t2], exp: 100, results: [:t5, :t6]},
  {ingredients: [:t3, :t4], exp: 200, results: [:t10]},
]
```

So it should check every element in the array and combine all the results of elements which contain the same ingredients array.

I don't really know where to start with this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `exp` outright neglected?

Comment: Yes it should just keep all the key value pairs from the first hash it finds.

Comment: What happened to `exp: 50`?

Comment: @sawa the OP want always the old value it seems.. :) I guess

Comment: @ArupRakshit It is not clear enough.

Comment: I know I know.. Whole post is confusing.. I read it wrong and my effort was wrong.. :(

Comment: Sorry I am not so good in explaining things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [ 
  {ingredients: [:t1, :t2], exp: 100, result: :t5},
  {ingredients: [:t3, :t4], exp: 200, result: :t10},
  {ingredients: [:t1, :t2], exp:  50, result: :t6}
]

array.reduce([]) { |memo, e|    # will build new array
  el = memo.find { |_e| _e[:ingredients] == e[:ingredients] }
  if el                         # already have same ingredients
    el[:results] << e[:result]   # modify 
    memo
  else
    e[:results] = [*e[:result]]  # append
    e.delete :result
    memo << e
  end 
}

#=> [
#  [0] {
#    :exp => 100,
#    :ingredients => [
#      [0] :t1,
#      [1] :t2
#    ],
#    :results => [
#      [0] :t5,
#      [1] :t6
#    ]
#  },
#  [1] {
#    :exp => 200,
#    :ingredients => [
#      [0] :t3,
#      [1] :t4
#    ],
#         :results => [
#      [0] :t10
#    ]
#  }
#]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please work on final output.. It is `results` not `result`.... Key having multiple values, should be having name like `results`..not `result`.

Comment: You should delete the `result` key after adding `results`.

Comment: Just do `memo.delete(:result)` at the end of the `if-else` block and then return `memo`.